# using curl for php xml generated http response

Tags: php, xml, http

I have an error

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity
```

i have two php files on the same server and am wanting to receive http response from php that generates xml

update.php

```
<?php

$url = '[pathtofile]response.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_file($response);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

and response.php

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>";
echo "<note>";
echo "<from>Jani</from>";
echo "<to>Tove</to>";
echo "<message>Remember me this weekend</message>";
echo "</note>";
?>
```

what causes to error?

Comment: `simplexml_load_file` requires a string containing a filename, you want `simplexml_load_string`. See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: Pekka is right - you already have the string, you are using the wrong function to interpret it (you are trying to access a file whose name is the contents of the file you fetched...) - and since such a file doesn't exist, you get the error you see.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example:

```
<?php
function download_page($path){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retValue;
}

$sXML = download_page('http://alanstorm.com/atom');
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);

foreach($oXML->entry as $oEntry){
    echo $oEntry->title . "\n";
}
```